# The probability that in a word made from a set of 16 letters exactly two are repeated

Tags: probability, combinations

A word of 6 letters is formed from a set of 16 different letters of English alphabets (with replacement). Find the probability that exactly two letters are repeated.

The answer is $\frac{18080}{16^6}$.

I would prefer different types of approaches to this problem.

#### Initial approach

I first thought of selecting 4 letters out of 16 and selected 2 out of them for repeating them and arranged. But that is not the answer.

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: I first thought of selecting 4 letters out of 16 and selected 2 out of them for repeating them and arranged. But that is not the answer.

Comment: Is it sure the answer is that fraction?

Comment: Does "two letters are repeated" mean that the same letter appears twice or that two different letters appear multiple times?  My answer assumes the latter.

Comment: I got the mistake in my method thanks to you, and ya, it's the latter. But I guess your answer doesn't match the one given above.

Comment: I suppose the  events we are interested in are in form AAAABB, AAABBB, AABBBB,....?

Comment: Exactly two letters repeated. That's right.

Comment: Is ABABAB considered the same as AAABBB, does order count?

Comment: It's a word. It should.

Answer (score 2):

There are ${16\choose 2}=120$ ways to select the two letters appearing repeatedly. Each selected pair is an ordered pair according to the order of letters in the English alphabet.

The selected letters occur in multiplicities $(x,y)$ where $x\geq2$, $y\geq2$. The possible multiplicities are

(i)  $\quad(4,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(2,4)$, occupying all six places,

(ii)  $\quad(3,2)$, $(2,3)$, occupying five places, and

(iii) $\quad (2,2)$, occupying four places.

In the cases (i)$(4,2)$ and (i)$(2,4)$ we can select the places of the first letter in ${6\choose4}={6\choose 2}=15$ ways, and in case (i)$(3,3)$ we can select the places of the first letter in ${6\choose 3}=20$ ways. This gives a total of $50$ possibilities for case (i).

In case (ii)$(3,2)$ we can select the places of the first letter in ${6\choose3}=20$ ways, then we can select the place to be left temporarily empty in $3$ ways, and finally we can fill this empty place with any of the  $14$ remaining letters, making a total of $840$ possibilities. This has to be doubled to take care of the case (ii)$(2,3)$ as well, so that we get $1680$ possibilities in all for case (ii).

In case (iii) we can place the first chosen letter in ${6\choose2}=15$ ways, then the second chosen letter in ${4\choose2}=6$ ways. Now there are two places left empty. For the lefthand empty spot  we have $14$ choices among the remaining letters, and for the righthand empty spot we have $13$ choices. In this way case (iii) amounts to $15\cdot 6\cdot 14\cdot 13=16380$ possibilities.

In all we obtain
$$120(50+1680+16380)=2173200$$
admissible words. This has to be divided by $16^6$ in order to arrive at the requested probability. The resulting value is $p=0.1295$.

The result we arrived at is different from the answer in your book. Maybe the exact meaning of "repeated" has to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can create every word with a repeated letter as follows: select two letters that are repeated, say $A$ and $B$.  Select the spaces (out of the $6$) that are to be occupied by $A$ and $B$ respectively.  Fill the remaining slots with whatever letters remain.

Multiplying the number of possible choices together, we have the following numerator for our fraction:
$$
\binom{16}{2}\cdot
\left(\binom{6}{2}\binom 42 14 \color{red}{\cdot 13}
+ 2\binom 63\binom 32 14 
+ 2\binom 64 \binom 22 
+ \binom 63 \binom 33\right)
$$
If we are not allowing any singly appearing letters, we'd have
$$
\binom{16}{2}\cdot
\left(2\binom 64 \binom 22 
+ \binom 63 \binom 33\right)
$$
Or, if you mean any word on a choice of two letters, we'd have 
$$
\binom{16}{2} \cdot \left(2^6 - 2\right)
$$

Comment: I didn't get the logic behind the statement you made. Please elaborate on it.

Comment: As in how did you get the last line as your numerator.

Comment: $\binom {16}2$: how many ways can we select two different letters?  $\binom 62 \binom 42$: given those letters, how many was can we select two slots for the first letter and two slots for the second letter?  $14^2$: given the two taken slots, how many ways can we fill the two slots left over with the remaining $14$ letters?

Comment: Did you calculate my answer? What does it come out to?  Did I overcount or undercount?

Comment: @Rohinb97 I think I figured out what I did wrong; I'll modify the answer.  Check if the new one works.

Comment: Still more than the actual answer. I think the part where you have considered counting the words formed by each repeated letter AABB is already included.

Comment: Are you there? It's still more than the answer.

Comment: Are you including words like ABABCD?  I assumed this was the case, which may be why I overcounted.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{225\times 224\times 156}{16^6}$$

The solution is as follows:

We first choose 5 letters from 16 different letters ie $\binom{16}5$ and then we have those 5 letters to be repeated.

$\binom{16}{5}\times 5$ and all the letters can be arranged in $6!$. As two letters are repeated so the solution must be divided by $2!$. Hence the answer is $$\frac{\binom{16}{5}\times 5\times 6!}{2! \cdot 16^6}$$